# Retrofit2 returns Fatal exception on get list of strings

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a get request for a `List<String>` and get a
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for java.util.List<java.lang.String>` - Fatal Exception

Do I make something wrong?

Model:

```kotlin
data class LocationWhitelistDto(
    val whitelist: List<String>? = null
)
```

Interface:

```kotlin
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface LockWhitelistService {
    @GET("/box/whitelist")
    fun get(): LocationWhitelistDto
}
```

Builder:

```kotlin
    val retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun whitelistProvider(): LockWhitelistService {
        return retrofitBuilder
            .build()
            .create(LockWhitelistService::class.java)
    }
```

I'm quite new at working with retrofit but, I have working requests with the builder. Has it something to do with the `@SerializedName` annotation? I can't use it because the response doesn't have any names, its just a List of Strings i get there.

Comment: So I have to make a complete custom CallAdapter for this simple request?!

Comment: you can't return the model class directly in API methods(in this case `LocationWhitelistDto`). you should wrap in a Call<>. therefore: `@GET("/box/whitelist")
    fun get(): Call<LocationWhitelistDto>`